# How to prove that $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$ has a unique solution, provided that $\forall x :f(x) \geq 0$?

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

Let $f$ be a real function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c:a\neq0$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb R:f(x) \ge0$.

I've proved that if $\sqrt{\Delta}=\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ exists, then $x=\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ or $x=\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$. Supposing that there exists $x:f(x)=0$, how to prove that $\sqrt{\Delta}$ exists and that it's equal to $0$?

Comment: Well, it is true that $\;f(x)=x^2+2x+2\ge0\;$ for all real $\;x\;$...and still $\;f(x)=0\;$ has no solution...Check carefully your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists $\;x_1\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)=0\;$ , then it is given by

$$x_1=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2a}\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;\;\Delta:=b^2-4ac$$

It thus must be that $\;\Delta\ge0\;$ , otherwise its square root is not a real number. **but** if $\;\Delta>0\;$ then there are two possibilities above because of the $\;\pm\;$ signs, and we thus get **a different** solution $\;x_2\;$ for $\;f(x)=0\;$. So we can say that

$$x_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt\Delta}{2a}\;,\;\;x_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt\Delta}{2a}$$

and because $\;\sqrt\Delta\neq0\;$ , we then get $\;x_1\neq x_2\;$ . Suppose $\;x_1<x_2\;$ , then:

$$f(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

but then, for **any** $\;x_1<d<x_2\;$ , we get $\;f(d)<0\;$ (since clearly $\;a>0\;$ ...why?) . Contradiction. Finish now the argument.

Comment: I used a proof from Wikipedia's article on quadratic equations for the formula of $x_1$ and at one point it takes a square root from $\Delta$ to achieve the final equation - using this equation to prove that $\sqrt{\Delta}$ exists is circular.

Comment: @asdasdfsss First, how in the word could I, or anyone else, know what you used, knew or studied if you did **not** make it clear in your question?! Second: the way the roots formula for a quadratic equation  is obtained makes it clear that there exists a *real* root iff $\;\Delta\ge0\;$ , meaning: iff we can take the square root of a non-negative real number.

Comment: Here is the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation. Is there a way to prove this formula without assuming that $\Delta \geq 0$? I need to prove that if the real root in question exists, then $\Delta \geq 0$, but with the derivation I linked the best I can get is $x=\dfrac{-b}{2a}±\sqrt{\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}$.

Comment: @asdasdfsss I really don't understand you: you have something like $\;t^2=u\;$ . In order to be able to *solve for* $\;t\;$ , in the field of real numbers of course, it **must be that** $\;u\ge0\;$ , otherwise *there is no real solution* ! Like $\;t^2=-2\;$  This thing has no *real* solution. So it is not a matter of proving the quadratic formula "without using" $\;\Delta\ge0\;$ : one **must assume** that otherwise we cannot advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two roots, $x_1< x_2$, then we can write it like $f(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ and then we have two cases:

$1)$ If $a>0$ then take a number $p$ such that $x_1<p<x_2$ and then we will have $f(p)<0$ what is a contradiction;

$2)$ If $a<0$ then take a number $p$ such that $p< x_1$ or $p>x_2$ and then we will have $f(p)<0$ what is a contradiction;

Otherwise, if $x_1=x_2$ then we can write $f(x)=a(x-x_1)^2$, with $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $a > 0$ otherwise the polynomial must became negative for some large $x$ or it is equal to the null polynomial and your solution is not unique.

Then for all $x$ you have :
$$ ax^2+bx+c  = a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2- \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a} =a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2- \frac{\Delta}{4a} $$
So your condition implies :
$$a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2- \frac{\Delta}{4a} \ge 0 \text{ so } a\left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2\ge \frac{\Delta}{4a}  $$
If we take the specific case $x=\frac{-b}{2a} $ we find $0\ge \Delta $. Now remember that any real solution requires that $\Delta \ge 0 $, and conclude that whenever a solution exists, it must be unique - and equals to $\frac{-b}{2a} $.